# implementing memory, program counter, and adder in Verilog. Confused regarding my output

Tags: memory, verilog

I am to design an adder, program counter, memory, clock, and test bench module.

I am suppose to initialize from the testbench, every memory address with 0, then load a .hex file that I have which is in the same directory as my program, into the memory. The text file looks like so:

"
...
...

20042000

000d2820

0c000013

.....
...."

I'm just having trouble loading the text.hex file into the memory. Here is my code:

```
module testbench; //create the testbench 

    instruction_memory memory();

    integer i;

    initial begin
    for(i=0; i<2048; i = i+1) begin
    memory.mem[i] = 0;
                              end
    end

        initial begin
        $writememh("text.hex",memory.mem);
        end

    integer m;

        initial begin
        for(m=0; m<2048; m = m+1) begin
        $display(memory.mem[m]);
        $display(m);
                                  end
        end    
endmodule //end the testbench

module instruction_memory(); // creating the module that 
                            //simulates the instruction //memory
    reg[31:0]mem[0:2047];

endmodule //ending the instruction memory module

module clock(); //starting the clock module

endmodule //ending the clock module

module pc(); //starting the program counter module

endmodule // ending the program counter module

module adder();

endmodule // ending the adder module
```

When I run it, my output looks like this:

```
0

1

0

2

0

3

...

...

0
2047
```

Why is it returning 0's instead of "000d2820" or some other word?

So I have one thing done. I initialized the memory with 0's, but I cant seem to read the file into it. How do I do this?

edit: this is my code now:

```
module testbench; //create the testbench 

    instruction_memory memory();

    integer i;
        initial begin
        for(i=0; i<2048; i = i+1) begin
        memory.mem[i] = 0;
                                  end
        end

    initial begin
    #100;
    end

    integer n;

        initial begin
        for(n=0; n<2048; n = n+1) begin
        $display(memory.mem[n]);
        $display(n);
                                  end
        end

    initial begin
    #100;
    end

    initial begin
        $readmemh("C:\\Users\\19724\\Desktop\\spring2020\\DL\\programs\\program3\\text.hex",memory.mem);
    end 

    initial begin
    #100;
    end

    integer m;

        initial begin
        for(m=0; m<2048; m = m+1) begin
        $display(memory.mem[m]);
        $display(m);
                                  end
        end    
endmodule //end the testbench

module instruction_memory(); // creating                                                            //the module that 
                            //simulates the instruction //memory

    reg[31:0]mem[0:2047];


endmodule //ending the instruction memory module
```

This code repeats the same output as above ^..

```
0

1

0

2

..

..

0

2047
```

except twice now that I have two loops displaying the out put after I initialize to zero, and after I "read the hex file," I put that in quotes because for some reason its not working even though I wrote the absolute path. Does anyone know why it wont read my hex file?

Comment: 1/ You have race conditions as you have three initial sections which will all start operating *at the same time in parallel!* 2/ You clear the memory but I don't see anywhere that you *"read the file into it"*

Comment: so how do I I keep them from operating in parallel? How do I initialize the instruction memory with zeros, then initialize every address that I have a value for, from my text.hex file, without doing this in parallel? And what do you mean I clear the memory, are you referring to when I initialize the memory with zeros? As for "read the file into it," I thought this is what I'm doing with "writememh("text.hex",memory.mem)"

Answer (score 1):

The following line creates an output file named `text.hex`:

```
    $writememh("text.hex",memory.mem);
```

You need to use `$readmemh` to read from an input file instead:

```
    $readmemh("text.hex", memory.mem);
```

Refer to the free IEEE Std 1800-2012, section *21.4 Loading memory array data from a file*.

Also, as pointed out in the comments, your 1st `initial` block assigns 0 to each memory location.  The 2nd `initial` block, using `$readmemh` conflicts with the 1st.  My guess is that you just need to keep the 2nd block.

Answer (score 1):

> so how do I I keep them from operating in parallel?
>   How do I initialize the instruction memory with zeros, then initialize every address that I have a value for, from my text.hex file, without doing this in parallel?
>   And what do you mean I clear the memory, are you referring to when I initialize the memory with zeros?
>   As for "read the file into it," I thought this is what I'm doing with "writememh("text.hex",memory.mem)"

Things get much simpler if you use single initial. I often split section by placing a delay between them which:

1. Makes it easier to see in my simulation waveform what happens.
2. Makes sure that the code is really executed sequentially.

Example:

```
...
initial
begin
   for(i=0; i<2048; i = i+1) begin
      memory.mem[i] = 0;

   #1000;

   $readmemh("text.hex",memory.mem);

   #1000;
   for(m=0; m<2048; m = m+1)
     $display(memory.mem[m]);

  $display(m);
end
....
```

Check your simulation log to see if the $readmemh gives an error message as simulators often need a special path to find the file.

Comment: I just cant seem to get it to work. I put the absolute path in $readmemh and it still doesn't work. I created an edit on my OP..

Comment: I can't help you any further. The only thing I can think of is to try different things in a single file: memory, $readmemh and display. Don't clear the memory, it will be all 'X' which may help debugging if you read only zeros. Check the file end-of-line. Maybe your $readmemh can't cope with e.g. CR and LF. File path: beware of `\\` file separators some simulators want '/' some need two to \\ get a single one etc.